# Select data by number of appearances

Tags: r, indexing

If I have a vector `c(2, 1, 0)` where the sum of the vector is always equal to the length of the vector, is it possible for me to select data from another vector in a way where I would get 2 of the first element, 1 of the second element, and none of the third element?  More generally, for vectors a and index, where `sum(index) == length(index)` I would get `index[i]` number of `a[i]`.

I hope this was clear enough, but its fairly muddled in my head.  I can implement this with loops, but I'd like a vector based solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 rep(letters[1:3], c(2, 1, 0))
#[1] "a" "a" "b"
```

I might add that the property that `sum(index) == length(index)` is not enforced. That would be something for which your process for constructing "index" remains responsible.